# Form validation not working when create a common file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#create_account").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myform').validate({
                rules: {
                    cs-username: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    cs-email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    cs-confirm-password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) { 
                    name = $("#cs-username").val();
                    email = $("#cs-email").val();
                    password = $("#cs-login-password").val();
                    cpassword = $("#cs-confirm-password").val();
                    alert(name);
                    alert(email);
                    alert(cpassword);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have simply create a common file i.e `footer.php` and I am using jquery form validation to validate my form but when I click on submit they are not working. So, How can I validate form? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Making sure, you have added Jquery before validation JS files -

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

And just call it on dom ready -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            cs-username: {
                required: true
            },
            cs-email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            cs-confirm-password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            name = $("#cs-username").val();
            email = $("#cs-email").val();
            password = $("#cs-login-password").val();
            cpassword = $("#cs-confirm-password").val();
            alert(name);
            alert(email);
            alert(cpassword);
        }
    });
});
```